# What is the basic meaning of 'dozy pillock'?

Tags: meaning

A character on "Last Tango in Halifax" often calls people a "dozy pillock" (not sure about the spelling for dozy.) I was trying to find a meaning for dozy and a better one for pillock than just knowing it is derogatory, and that is how I found your wonderful website.

I'm American (Albuquerque, New Mexico) and have loved TV shows and movies from Great Britain all my life, though I am often confused by their English and usually try to find an answer to my confusion.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you checked here https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130908174705AA656EY?

Answer (score 6):

In the context you supplied, *dozy* means 'stupid'.

[*Pillock*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pillock?r=66) has its origin as one of the numerous slang terms for 'penis', but today I think that association has receded from most people's consciousness, and it is now a derogatory term that usually conveys the meaning of 'a person who is an idiot, or who has done something stupid or silly'.

Comment: Yes, the term 'pillock' is now more associated with 'idiot' http://it.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Pillock

Comment: By the way, I looked at that precious link that @Kiran left me, and it said that pillock meant "a little testicle" but that  meaning isn't used any more.

Comment: @user85356 - You'll have to decide who you're going to believe: a reputable dictionary, or an unsourced assertion from some credential-less who-knows-who on Yahoo. If you don't think Dictionary.com is good enough, look up the word on the www.OneLook.com metadictionary, which will link you to numerous other online dictionaries. I presume they can't *all* be wrong in their research.

Answer (score 1):

Having been born in the UK, I and many others have used the term Dozy Pillock for someone who has done something stupid or downright dangerous. Not knowing the full meaning or derivation does in no way deter people from making such a comment. It is akin to Dill or Dickhead or Bampot from Scotland.

Answer (score 0):

Daft twit, would be about as good a translation. Not so much derogatory, but often used affectionately.